# Connection between Android and MySql DataBase

Tags: java, android, mysql

I would like some help in order to create an application on Android that connects to my data base(MySql) .Is there any way to connect directly?
I know to connect from Java to data base , but on Android I had no success.

Comment: You shouldn't connect directly to your database from a mobile device-  doing so requires your database server to be open to the world, its not secure.  Use a webservice to pass data from the db to the device

Comment: Maybe... maaaaaaaaaayyyyyyybe he has a good reason to do this

Comment: Petrica, no one is going to answer if all you do is down-vote the people who answer

Comment: ^ Agreed. I'm not sure what else you're looking for. You've been given multiple valid solutions to your issue.

Answer (score 2):

The proper method of doing this is to create APIs (REST) (in PHP for instance) which will handle all communication with the database. Then you'll simply call these APIs from your app. By doing this instead of handling the DB connection natively, you avoid having to republish your app for minor logic changes as you can simply update the PHP code.

Using a library to help handle async callbacks can be super helpful for this.

This is the one I usually use:

**[LoopJ's Async HTTP Callback Library](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)**

This will handle GET and POST requests with a lot of cool features such as custom timeouts, JSON format, onSuccess() and onFailure() methods, etc. There's a lot of working examples of this library too.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just doing everything locally? If so, use this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/). If you are trying to save to a cloud my favorite I have used is [Parse.com](https://parse.com/).

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create a service or an API that talks to your Database. Your Andriod app will then communicate with this service using HTTP protocol. I'd recommend creating a restful service that can take in and return in JSON format. Take a look at the link below. It is not recommended to open MYSQL port for remote connection.

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/calling-restful-services-from-your-android-app/